# Simplifying SQL SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a query that pulls a rolling 36 month unit sales history. It works as-is, but I wondered if there was a way to make it less lengthy and cumbersome.

There are two parts to the query as it stands - the headers and the data.

**Here is what I have for the headers:**

```
SELECT  
DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM36"
, DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM35"
, DATEADD(m, -34, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM34"
```

As of today, this is Sep - Nov 2011. It goes on to...

```
, DATEADD(m, -03, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM03"
, DATEADD(m, -02, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM02"
, DATEADD(m, -01, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM01"
```

June - Aug 2014. 36 lines of code.

**The statements to pull the unit sales data are as follows:**

```
, SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty"  ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty36"
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -34, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty35"
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -34, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -33, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty34"
```

As of today, this is Sep - Nov 2011. It goes on to...

```
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -03, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -02, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty03"
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -02, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -01, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty02"
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -01, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -00, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty01"
```

June - Aug 2014.

I'm going to have a lot more to add before this report is done so I want to keep things as tidy as possible.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

The example below shows that with the above code I am able to get what I want (don't have the rep to post images so I had to do a link). It also shows that with the pivot table I am missing my item numbers and the rolling months. How do I add those two things?

[Example](http://sosteppenwolf.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/5/2/13528680/3121032_orig.png)

I tried dropping the "ItemTable"."ItemNum" field in as follows, but it doesn't show up in my Crystal Report. Anywhere else I tried to put it, I get "could not be bound" error.

```
select 
[0] MM00
, [1] MM01
, [2] MM02
, ...
from (
select 
  "ItemTable"."ItemNum",DateDiff(m, "SalesTable"."SalesDate", GetDate()) months_ago
, "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" NetQty
from your_table
) as source
pivot 
(
 sum(NetQty) For months_ago in ([0], [1], [2], [3], ...)
) as PivotTable
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Make a one month query and wrap it in a WHILE loop that increments from 1 to 36.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation seems ripe for a [Pivot table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

Something along the lines of

```
select 
    [0] MM00
  , [1] MM01
  , [2] MM02
  , ...
from (
  select 
      DateDiff(m, "SalesTable"."SalesDate", GetDate()) months_ago
    , "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" NetQty
  from your_table
) as source
pivot 
(
  sum(NetQty) For months_ago in ([0], [1], [2], [3], ...)
) as PivotTable
```

**Edit**

Refining the example: Including the item number is fairly straight forward; just include it in the select statement.

```
select 
    "ItemTable"."ItemNum"
  , [0] MM00
  , [1] MM01
  , [2] MM02
  , ...
from (
  select
      "ItemTable"."ItemNum" 
    , DateDiff(m, "SalesTable"."SalesDate", GetDate()) months_ago
    , "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" NetQty
  from your_table
) as source
pivot 
(
  sum(NetQty) For months_ago in ([0], [1], [2], [3], ...)
) as PivotTable
```

Having dynamic names for your pivot columns is rather more difficult.  The general idea is that you have to build the SQL as a string and execute it dynamically.  A Google search yields a number of results (such as [a SQL Hints blog](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)).  Some incomplete code to give you the general idea would be.

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
 N'select 
    "ItemTable"."ItemNum"
  , [' + @Name1 + ']
  , [' + @Name2 + ']
  , [' + @NameN + ']
from (
  select
      "ItemTable"."ItemNum" 
      /* search MSDN for the best date formatting algorithm */
    , CONVERT_TO_STRING("SalesTable"."SalesDate") month 
    , "SalesTable"."SalesQty" - "SalesTable"."ReturnsQty" NetQty
  from your_table
) as source
pivot 
(
  sum(NetQty) For month in (
      [' + @Name1 + ']
    , [' + @Name2 + ']
    , [' + @NameN + ']
  )
) as PivotTable';

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Something like this is definitely more efficient. See my edit above where I can expound on what I've got so far.

Comment: Awesome. Got the ItemNum to show up. Only thing I had to do differently was to drop the table name ("ItemTable".) below the first SELECT operator. Not sure about the rationale there, but it works. I'll have to toy with the dynamic names to see if I can get it to work. You helped me make progress, though, so thanks.